# iOS: Progress bar in a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, nsurlsession, uiprogressview

I have 2 view controllers. In the parent view, i have a progress view. In the child VC, I am uploading an image with parameters using POST request to the server and then dismissing that VC and hence on returning to parent VC, I want progress View to update as the upload is happening. I tried protocol-delegate method, but looks like it only works once and can't return values dynamically. I tried implementing the following method in both view controllers but no success.

```
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {

    self.progressView.hidden = false
    self.uploadProgress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
    print(self.uploadProgress)
    self.progressView.setProgress(self.uploadProgress, animated: true)

    if (uploadProgress == 1.0) {
        self.progressView.hidden = true
//            uploadProgress = 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: will both the VC be visible at same time ?

Comment: @Shubhank No, Child VC is being dismiised

Comment: then delegate method should work fine

Comment: @Shubhank maybe i am implementing that wrong, but shouldn't delegate method work once when we will dismiss VC. I tried calling it in above URLSession method too, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on KVO (Key-Value observing) and observe your `self.uploadProgress`. Each time the `self.uploadProgress` is change a function will be called and then you can do whatever you want. Make sure to add the observer (function) on the VC you want to show the progress bar.

For example in ParentVC:

```
[childVC addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"uploadProgress" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"uploadProgress"]) {
        NSLog(@"Updated Value:%@",[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]);
        //Do something
    }
}
```

observeForValue will be called each time uploadProgress property change.

Don't forget to remove observer when you don't need it or when ChildVC will be destroyed.

```
-(void)dealloc {

    [self removeObserver:parentVC forKeyPath:@"uploadProgress"];
}
```

Comment: I will try this in a while. Thanks, will let you know if this worked.

Comment: Make sure that the reference from childVC to parentVC is weak in order to avoid retain cycle

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my own code worked. All I had to do was put the progress code inside dispatch_async.

Comment: in main queue or background queue? If it's not in the main queue then probably your app will crash in the future since updating the UI from a background thread will cause a lot of issues. Anw take a look on KVO approach. It's ideal for that kind of issues

Comment: It's in the main queue.